# How to JOIN SELECT from multiple tables, where the SELECTS is based on different conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have three tables. One with notes `Notes`, one with users `Users`, and one a relational table between users and notes `NotesUsers`.

Users

```
user_id    first_name    last_name
1          John          Smith
2          Jane          Doe
```

Notes

```
note_id    note_name     owner_id
1          Math          1
2          Science       1
3          English       2
```

NoteUsers

```
user_id    note_id   
1          1          
2          1  
2          2          
2          3
```

Hopefully, from the select statement you can tell what I'm trying to do. I am trying to select the notes that `user_id = 2` has access to but doesn't necessarily own, but also along with this I'm trying to get the first and last name of the owner.

```
SELECT Notes.notes_id, note_name
FROM Notes, NotesUsers
WHERE NotesUsers.note_id = Notes.note_id AND NotesUsers.user_id = 2 
JOIN SELECT first_name, last_name FROM Users, Notes WHERE Notes.owner_id = Users.user_id
```

My problem is that because the `WHERE` clause for `first_name`, and `last_name` versus that for `notes` are different, I don't know how to query the data. I understand that this is not how a `JOIN` works and 
I don't necessarily want to use a `JOIN`,  but I'm not sure how to structure the statement, so I left it in there so that you can understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can join `Notes` with `NoteUsers` to check for access and with `Users` to add the user's details to the result:

```
SELECT n.noted_id, n.note_name, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM   Notes n
JOIN   NoteUsers nu ON n.noted_id = nu.note_id AND nu.user_id = 2
JOIN   Users u ON n.owner_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you need here to use a query inside the main query. MySQL will return first all the `note_id` that the user with `user_id = 2` has access to from `NoteUser`, then well build the outer query to return the `first_name` and the `last_name` of the owner.

```
    SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, n.note_name, n.note_id
    FROM Notes AS n
    LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.user_id = n.owner_id
    WHERE n.note_id IN 
       (SELECT nu.note_id FROM NoteUser WHERE nu.user_id = 2)
```